# Error compiling with WiX. light.exe is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, wix3.10

Having an issue compiling a project on Visual Studio 2015 with WiX toolset 3.10.

I compiled an x64 project with no problems.  Switched to x86 to compile the 32-bit version (only change) and now I get the following error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Bootstrapper    light.exe

I have two Wix Projects (Setup and Setup64) to manage the two proc type installations.

**Steps taken so far**

1) Restarted visual studio - No change

2) Made sure that the MSBuild processes are cleared in Task Manager - no change

3) Changed maximum number of parallel project builds in Tools > Options to 1 - no change

4) Switched back to x64 - Still getting the error.

This is a big issue for me because I am expected to get a new version out today.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The only way I can get it to compile a second time is to restart my computer completely.  Any advice on how I can get VS to release light.exe?

Comment: It appears as though an open bug about one or more of the Media cabs specified in the projects becoming locked and a sharing violation occurs within Light.exe:https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4095.

Comment: The really odd thing to me is that I didn't make any changes (that I can think of) to the Wix installer projects that have been compiling fine for months.